# Does gravatar do a redirect to my server or host the default image on it's servers?

Tags: html, redirect, avatar, gravatar

If I provide a default image to gravatar using the `d` parameter (for users who are not registered with gravatar), will gravatar redirect to the server hosting this default image or will it cache the image on it's server?

Example link: `//gravatar.com/avatar/asdfs3rwerwesdfadsfas3/?d="mysite/img.jpg"`. Will gravatar cache `img.jpg` or does it redirect to `mysite` each time?

Comment: That would be pretty easy to find out by trying it and looking at the HTTP response headers. :)

Comment: @deceze Aha, did that. Seems like gravatar hosts the image! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the response headers as suggested by @deceze in the comments. Gravatar hosts the image on it's domain (`http://i*.wp.com/imagename`). There is no redirect involved.